# Django-pipeline is post-processing static html files

Tags: django, django-pipeline

I'm using Django-pipeline to minify my static files and synced to S3. Everything works great when I want to minify and concatenate my JS and CSS files, but when I run "collectstatic", it also seems to be versioning/cache-busting my static html (AngularJS partials) files as well, which I don't want. Is there a way to ignore my static html files? I have a feeling that I need to write some logic to ignore these static html files in my custom app storage, but I'm not really quite sure.

It's doing something like this:

```
Post-processed 'app/partials/loading_spinner.html' as 'app/partials/loading_spinner.b283c2089f5f.html'
```

My STATICFILE_STORAGES is set to the following:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin
from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```